# SharePoint 2010: Calendar list's "All Items" view not allowing a formula in calculated field

Tags: sharepoint, types, formula

I initially made a general custom list in SP 2010 where my formula worked without issue.

Then used same column names and data type in Calendar list's "All Items" view and getting this ERROR:

> One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are
>   defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.

Here is the formula:

```
=IF([EVENT TYPE]="Blue",0,  
IF([EVENT TYPE]="Build(nonBlue)",1,  
IF([EVENT TYPE]="Pink",2,  
IF([EVENT TYPE]="Cutoff",4,  
IF([EVENT TYPE]="Today",5,  
IF([EVENT TYPE]="Other",6,  
"#N/A - Select valid event type"))))))
```

The "EVENT TYPE" column is a Choice column with list of choices referenced in formula.

The returned data type in both the "general" SharePoint custom list (that is working) and the Calendar's "All Items" view is "Single line of text"

For the Calendar list I have tried changing return data format to number. I've also tried putting all the numbers in my formula in quotation with the 'single line of text' return data type.

It's baffling why same formula is working in one list, but not the other, with all the same settings for columns involved.

There are other calculated columns in same Calendar list, that reference other Choice columns in that list and are working fine.

I've tried both cutting/pasting the formula, and re-typing the formula in case column name wasn't identical. I get the same error, that it's a data type error.

All the web search I've done mentions using choice columns is allowed. I'm thinking it has something to do with the Calendar specific list, but as I mentioned, I have other calculated formulas in same list that are working.

Comment: The two lists (the general custom list where the formula is working, and the other Calendar "All Items" list where formula is not being accepted) are not connected at all, and don't cross reference any columns.

Comment: Tried something else. Wrote formula pointing to another choice column ("=[Choice Column2]), and it worked and returns the value selected in "Choice Column2".  Then tried formula ("=[EVENT TYPE]) and I'm getting same data type error. So something to do with that column. All settings for both choice columns are the same, just 2 choices in "Choice Column2" and 7 in the EVENT COLUMN.

Comment: Still need help figuring out what could be the issue with the column if anyone has any suggestions? Thanks